# Run script until current line

Tags: spyder

Is there a hotkey for running the script from the beginning to the current line where the cursor is positioned? I know this can be done by selecting all code and hitting F9. However, I am wondering if this can be done by a single key/combination of keys.

Comment: Do you mean with Spyder right? I think a PR adding such functionality is in process of being merged. The PR for the functionality: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/16509

Comment: Got it, thanks! That would be super handy. Thanks also for your great work on Spyder!

Comment: Thank you! And glad to know that new features will be useful for more people :)